# Taking Int values out of a map and iterating them into a bipartite graph C++

Tags: c++, loops, bipartite

This is fairly complex for me, hopefully its not for others.

I have a set of `256` key/value items in a map. I got the data into the map from a text file via an `ifstream`. Now, I need to take the key/value pairs from the map and I need to use these data points to create a *Bipartite Mapping graph*.

What I need to do is to is to iterate through each key and value and put them inside the `bpGraph` in the format:

```
bool bpGraph[V][V] = { {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ect.... 0}, //Key 1 Value 4
                        {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, ect.... 0}, // Key 2 Value 2
                        {0, 0},
                        {0, 0},
                        {0, 0},
                        {0, 0},
                        {0, 0}
                      };
```

Essentially I will look through the map and set all the 256 values in this 256x256 array and set the right value to true with the key being the horizontal row and value being the vertical row.

This is the code I have currently:

```
int main(){

    ifstream myfile("H:\\School\\CSC-718\\paths.txt"); 
    std::map<int, int> mymap;
    pair<int,int> me;
    char commas;
    int a, b;
    vector<int> v;

    while (myfile >> a >> commas >> b){
        mymap[a] = b;
    }
    mymap;

    bool bpGraph[M][N] = {
        //...
    };

    cout << "Maximum number networks "
         << maxBPM(bpGraph);

    return 0;
}
```

### Question:

Could I have some advice/suggestions regarding the implementation?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you need `std::ifstream` and why `std::map`? Please explain what is input (`ifsream` or `map`).

Comment: @LukášBednařík Let me know if my explanation above makes more sense now

Comment: Do you want to know how to iterate an std::map and get all keys and values? Can you explain what the values in bpGraph should be?

Comment: @user779446 Yes I want to iterate through the Map and get each key and value and put it into the bpgraph. The values would be comma separated pairs of two ints as shown in the first code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the map using an iterator. From the iterator you can extract the key and the value using the 'first' and 'second' members respectively. Then you can put these values in your array.

For the following code, iterates a map and prints each key and the associated value:

```
void MapExample(void)
{
    std::map<int, int> mymap;

    mymap[1] = 11;
    mymap[2] = 22;
    mymap[3] = 33;

    for (std::map<int,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin();it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << "->" << it->second << "\n";
    }
}
```

The above prints

1->11

2->22

3->33

**EDIT:**
I am not sure if I understand correctly, but if I do, you want to build an equivalent representation of your data, that uses a 256x256 array instead of a map.

So iterating the map you would do:

```
    for (std::map<int,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin();it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    {
         int key = it->first;
         int value = it->second;

         bpGraph[key-1][value-1] = 1;  //the indexes to the array are zero based, so you need to subtract 1, if your keys and values belong to {1, ... ,256}
    }
```

Note that you need to initialize all array elements to zero. After the execution of the for loop, V[i][j]=1 only if key (i+1) is associated with value (j+1).

Comment: I further explained the problem above. Please let me know if it makes more sense what I am trying to do.